# Помогите запустить проект на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, openserver, freemarker

мне нужно запустить один проект, я склонировал его с git себе на компьютер, закинул все файлы в OSPanel\domains.
После запуска у меня появилась ошибка, можете подсказать, что с ней делать? 
[image: yii2 error]

Comment: `composer install/update`?

Comment: [скрин терминала](https://prnt.sc/q0yhv9), не помогло, ввёл обе команды

Comment: Потому-что вы не поняли намека. Вас спросили - пытались ли вы установить Yii2 через `composer` , вместо того, что бы тянуть весь исходный код с гихаба? Как это сделать - есть подробнейшая инструкция в документации к Yii2. Гуглите.

Comment: Это же уже готовый проект, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: А. вы пытались установить себе не фреймворк. А готовый макет. Извините, ошибся)
Ну что ж.  Тогда гляньте еще раз что у вас написано в ошибке. Внимательнее. Там исчерпывающая информация.

Answer (score 1):

```
php yii init
```

после скачивания не прописывал? похоже что проект не инициализирован.